# "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY firebase-admin@6.1.0"

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I'm getting this error message:

```
npm list -g --depth=0   

/Users/TDK/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY firebase-admin@6.1.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: firebase-admin@~6.0.0, required by firebase-functions@2.1.0
```

I ran

```
npm -g uninstall firebase-admin --save
```

Then I ran

```
npm -g install firebase-admin --save
```

Should I run this again without `--save`, or uninstall and reinstall an older version? 6.1.0 is the latest version, released two weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting back to `firebase-admin 6.0.0` worked.

```
npm -g uninstall firebase-admin --save  

npm -g install firebase-admin@6.0.0 --save

npm list --depth=0              
functions@ /Users/TDK/LanguageTwo/functions
├── @google-cloud/storage@2.3.0
├── firebase-admin@6.0.0
├── firebase-functions@2.1.0
```